# QGIS2threejs vector wall in angle

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

I have 3D map in QGIS2threejs where I have vector line and for Object type I use **wall** and for style I set Other side Z expression to -2000 which represents depth of -2km.

This is now vertical but this should be in angle so is there are a way to manipulate data visible in attribute table or to change some settings that this is in angle like blue line on the image I draw?

[image]